# Import CSV file to PostgreSQL with file headers

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a wide data set that is 62 columns wide. I'm aware that I can manually set out the columns in PostgreSQL but that too much time, especially if I have to import even wider datasets in the future.

I've found a solution online involving [pgfutter](https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter/releases) but this no longer works in PostgreSQL 13. What are my other options available to me?

Comment: Well, you only need to write the column names once. So what's the big deal?

Comment: Take a look at [csv2db](https://github.com/csv2db/csv2db). I have not used it so cannot comment on its performance. It creates a staging table for getting the data into the database. Another option would be [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) `from_csv` and `to_sql`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's an issue when you are 60-150columns wide. You're right that I can manually input it, but why not got the extra step and be efficient in our work too?